# Laravel multilingual routes

Tags: routes, laravel-5, multilingual

I am learning Laravel and I would like to know how to make multilingual routes with optional lang parameter. I tried this:

     `Route::get( '{lang?}/somewhere/{id?}', 'PageController@somewhere' )
         ->where([ 'lang' => '(en|fr|sk)', 'id' => '\d+' ])
         ->name( 'page.somewhere' );`

but it does not work as optional param. Also as I read here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/multi-language-routes-and-url it is quite tricky. What is the best practice to achieve this?

Thank you.